# Removing beginning and end of a string

Tags: r

I have:

```
c("Enrolment in secondary school, private school")
```

and I'd like to have

```
c("secondary school)
```

`Enrolment in` and the first `,` are fixed patterns.

I'm not at all familiar with regular expressions. Can someone help out?

Comment: `stringr::str_replace(str, "Enrolment in (.+),.+", "\\1")` will probably do the trick. Brackets define a grouping which can be referenced later in order (i.e. the `n`th set of brackets can be referenced with `\\n`).  Obviously it's not a very resilient regex, but it passes your test case.

Comment: Thanks Akhil but this expression only removes the "Enrolment in" part but not the "," and everything after it.

Comment: Did you include the `,.+` after the closed bracket? Works fine for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some alternatives.  They do not use any packages and they all work if `x` is a single string or a vector of strings (except (3) which is only for a single string -- (3a) is the vector version of (3)).

They use this input:

```
x <- "Enrolment in secondary school, private school"
```

**1) gsub**  This replaces the prefix and the suffix with the empty string in one go:

```
gsub("Enrolment in |,.*", "", x)
## [1] "secondary school"
```

**2) sub** This does the same but in separate `sub` invocations:

```
sub(",.*", "", sub("Enrolment in ", "", x))
## [1] "secondary school"
```

**2a) sub/substring** Since we know the length of the prefix we could replace one of the `sub` calls with `substring`:

```
sub(",.*", "", substring(x, 14))
## [1] "secondary school"
```

**3) strsplit**  Although one would not normally use this solution one could use strsplit as shown:

```
strsplit(x, "Enrolment in |,.*")[[1]][2]
## [1] "secondary school"
```

**3a)** To generalize (3) to a vector of strings:

```
sapply(strsplit(x, "Enrolment in |,.*"), "[", 2)
## [1] "secondary school"
```

**4) read.table**  This replaces the prefix with a comma and then reads it as comma-separated fields using `read.table` picking off the second column:

```
read.table(text = sub("Enrolment in ", ",", x), sep = ",", as.is = TRUE)[[2]]
## [1] "secondary school"
```

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
library(stringr)

str = c("Enrolment in secondary school, private school")

str_extract(str, "(?<=Enrolment in )([^,]+)")
#> [1] "secondary school"
```

You could also do it by:

1. Removing "Enrolment in"
2. Splitting on a comma
3. Taking the first part of it

For instance:

```
(remove_enrol <- gsub("Enrolment in ", "", str))
#> [1] "secondary school, private school"

(result = strsplit(remove_enrol, ",")[[1]][[1]])
#> [1] "secondary school"
```